# eslint use for loop or forEach

Tags: javascript, eslint

There is eslint rule `unicorn/no-array-for-each` ([link](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/blob/main/docs/rules/no-array-for-each.md)).

```
Use `for…of` instead of `Array#forEach(…)`            unicorn/no-array-for-each
```

Motivation for unicorn's rule is that it supports early return and is claimed to be faster. For an array like `itemList = [{a:1},{a:2},{a:3}]`.

```
for (const item of itemList) {
    if (item.a > 1) break;
    console.log(item.a)
}
```

However, it would go into eslint error `no-restricted-syntax` ([link](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax)).

```
iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately, loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations  no-restricted-syntax
```

It says for loop is heavyweight. It seems these two rules conflict with each other, which one makes more sense to be enabled?

Comment: If you are gonna use `break`, just go with the traditional `for-loop`

Comment: You can find many rules that are in conflict with each other. After all, ESLint is modular and configurable - if you create a configuration that disallows the code you write, it's not really ESLint's fault. With that said, there are at least two fundamental problems with your question: 1. It's a false dilemma. You can also use a traditional `for` loop which satisfies both rules. 2. The `no-restricted-syntax` rule is relevant if you're transpiling your code in which case a `for...of` will require more code to transpile. If you're *not* transpiling the code, it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @VLAX said, traditional `for` loop satisfies both rules.

```
for (let index = 0, l = itemList.length; index < l; index += 1) {
    const item = itemList[index];
    if (item.a > 1) break;
    console.log(item.a)  
}
```